# How to get intent and use its File in a method/function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have a little "problem on / question for" android studio / kotlin.

In my project i do parse a pdf-file or to say, i extract some text out of it.
It is working and full testet on kotlin - IntelliJ IEAA with a given File "c:../test.pdf".

Now in android studio, i want to let the user pick the file with setonclicklistener.
So an file explorer is coming up, that's not the problem.

But how to handle the intent now?
My function is asking for a File.

> "private fun checkRightFile(document: File): String { .... }"
>
> var checkedFile = checkRightFile( "Intent to File" here) <<<<

How do i use the intent to "make" it be a File?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "So an file explorer is coming up, that's not the problem" -- your [mcve] should show what you are doing here. "My function is asking for a File" -- most likely, you will need to change that. "How do i use the intent to "make" it be a File?" -- most likely, you don't. If you are using something like `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, neither are limited to files on the filesystem, and you are not getting a file, but a `Uri`. Perhaps your `checkRightFile()` function could be adjusted to work with an `InputStream`; use `ContentResolver` `openInputStream()` to get one for the `Uri`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Sorry for my misstake at posting. Need to say, somehow it was running as i use Inputfilestream instead of File but i commented it out and deleted it by misstake. And had no clue how to reproduce it cuz i was fixed to use it as File. Will try it again later at home.